# How do I get email autofill for iOS in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, autofill

I already know that you simply have to put `emailAddress` for `textContentType` as seen from the [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype-ios).

But when I do this, it doesn't seem to suggest my email. My email is definitely apart of my Apple account, and it has no problem autofilling my first and last name.

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332848/how-can-i-get-email-autocomplete-suggestions-for-ios-in-react-native-with-textco), but my problem is that I'm using expo and not Xcode to build my project.

Does anyone have any ideas or a lead I can go off on? Or a similar solution to the stackoverflow question that applies to expo?

Here's the code if you're curious:

```
<TextInput
  id="email"
  placeholder="Email (optional)"
  returnKeyType="done"
  textContentType="emailAddress"
  keyboardType="email-address"
  autoFocus={true}
  maxLength={25}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  autoCapitalize={"none"}
  onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
  onSubmitEditing={() => {
    dispatch(setProgress(0));
    props.navigation.navigate("ReadyToBuild");
  }}
  initialValue=""
  value={inputState.value}
  placeholder={props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : "type here..."}
  placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
  onChangeText={textChangeHandler}
  onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
  ref={props.inputRef}
  styleInput={{
    fontSize: 28,
    fontWeight: "300",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    marginHorizontal: "5%",
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Even using Expo, you could install XCode and follow that part of the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332848/how-can-i-get-email-autocomplete-suggestions-for-ios-in-react-native-with-textco