# React Native: How to show email autocompletion in TextInput field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is it possible in Expo / React Native to have email autocompletion when a user types in their email address in a TextInput?

For example when I use the app I'm working on my phone and type in `john@` my keyboard gives me suggestions for gmail.com, outlook.com, and yahoo.com.

[Screenshot of result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lme5a.jpg)

I have been trying to get this to work on my iOS Simulator and Android Emulator but can't get this result.

On `Expo: 46.0.7` and `React Native: 0.69.6`

These are the properties that I have for my `TextInput` field

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={handleEmailChange}
  editable={true}
  placeholder={'Enter a value...'}
  keyboardType="email-address"
  textContentType='emailAddress'
  returnKeyType="done"
  returnKeyLabel="done"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  autoComplete="email"
  ref={emailRef}
  blueOnSubmit={Platform.OS === "ios" ? true : false}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `inputmode='email'` https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#inputmode

If that doesn't work try this for iOS : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017919/10657559

Comment: As of RN v0.73, it works on iOS as well